# Update-Site for Mylyn Web Templates Connector (a.k.a. generic web connector) is unknown

Tags: eclipse, mylyn, update-site

I want to install the Web Templates Connector for Mylyn in Eclipse. It was also known as Generic Web Connector in the past.

There's an infinite count of pages on the web that mention http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/incubator/3.5/ as the update site, including the official documentation and some answers here on SO. However, that site is 404.

Some pages also mention http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/ but this only references back to the above 404 URL (or some variant therof, which is also 404).

**Does anybody know where the actual update site can be found?**

Answer (score 2):

That 404 can be ignored.  It is Eclipse's special way of telling you that the location is not for human consumption.  If you use that in your Eclipse update panel you will note that it will correctly list available features at that location (I just tried it and it worked).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, the installation did not work, but now I found out that this was not caused by that 404, but by some other misconfiguration of my eclipse setup.